# algining text to center in label in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M1FT.png)

I want to align the text of label l to centre so that it doesnot look weird. How can i do that?Thnks in advance.

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

def func(event):
    if len(entry1.get())==0 and len(entry3.get())==0 and len(entry5.get())==0:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Oops!","You have not entered even a single item")
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Cheers!","You will be notified when the price of any of your item(s) drop(s)")

root=Tk() #blank window
root.title("Amazon Price Drop Alert")
root.geometry("500x400")

l=Label(root,text="Enter the ASIN No or ISBN No(for books) in ItemID Field.\n Both of these descriptions can be found in product description of an item \n You can enter upto 3 items\n\n\n")

l1=Label(root,text="ItemID\n")
l3=Label(root,text="ItemID\n")
l5=Label(root,text="ItemID\n")

entry1=Entry(root)
entry3=Entry(root)
entry5=Entry(root)

l.grid(row=0,column=10)
l1.grid(row=1,column=19,sticky=E)
entry1.grid(row=1,column=20)
l3.grid(row=5,column=19,sticky=E)
entry3.grid(row=5,column=20)
l5.grid(row=8,column=19,sticky=E)
entry5.grid(row=8,column=20)

button=Button(root,text="Submit")
button.grid(row=10,column=20)
button.bind("<Button-1>",func)

root.mainloop()#window displays constantly root = Tk()
```

I am using tkinter for gui.

Answer (score 0):

Text is by default centered inside the Label area. To expand the label across the two columns, you can use the `colspan` attribute of grid.

Since you have your labels in col 19 and your entries column 20, you can try

```
l.grid(row=0,column=19,columnspan=2)
```